# Running pytest test giving error for pluggy, is there something wrong with setup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to run the pytest test.py file which contains tests for the project I am working on. Earlier the test was running fine but suddenly they stopped running with an error for pluggy package.

I have tried finding the issue but could not resolve, is there something related to virtualenv setup or pluggy package? Tried removing that but could not help?

This is the test I am running :

```
import subprocess
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

class Test:

    def test_yank_case(self):
    subprocess.call('echo Yanking case testing started', shell=True)
    assert subprocess.call('echo | yank 02041523', shell=True) == 0
```

Running as below with error:

Expected results should be pytest running with all test green.

But getting below error:

```
[apaliwal@dhcp223-39 supportshell]$ pytest test/test.py 
=============================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.2.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
rootdir: /home/apaliwal/Support_shell_test_repo/supportshell, inifile:
plugins: dependency-0.3.2, cov-2.6.1, bdd-3.1.0
collected 8 items                                                                                                                                                                                                 

test/test.py 
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 203, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 243, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 284, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 68, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 62, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 264, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 284, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 68, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 62, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 78, in pytest_runtest_protocol
INTERNALERROR>     runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 87, in runtestprotocol
INTERNALERROR>     rep = call_and_report(item, "setup", log)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 175, in call_and_report
INTERNALERROR>     report = hook.pytest_runtest_makereport(item=item, call=call)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 284, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 68, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 62, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 203, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     gen.send(outcome)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_dependency.py", line 136, in pytest_runtest_makereport
INTERNALERROR>     marker = item.get_marker("dependency")
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'get_marker'
```

I am really not sure why pluggy is been used in pytest and can I remove it to fix the issue?
Please provide help

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pytest-dependency`, because version 0.3.2 is too old for changes introduced in pytest 4.

Comment: Thanks, @hoefling for helping on this

Answer (score 1):

As per comment for my question below command can resolve the outdated dependency.

```
pip install --upgrade pytest-dependency
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18